# Generate SQL based on a matrix of data

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have a Permission/Roles matrix in a spreadsheet, and in each cell for the Permission/Role, I have a 'y' in that cell to see if that role has that permission.

Roles are listed along the top, and permissions down the left side, with the middle area cells using a y if that role has that permission.

What I need to do is, for each checked cell, get the value from the permission list on the left, and the value of the role above, and generate something:

```
="INSERT INTO table (RoleID, PermissionID) VALUES (" & Value of the Role & ", " & value of the permission &")"
```

And then add that to a list of SQL scripts on a different sheet, so that I can then select them all and past into a query window.

Is there a way to iterate through each cell in the matrix, if it has a 'y', create a string and put that into a different cell?

I have attached the sheet I am testing with:
[Sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/56eu8d0yj5ulcpx/Permissions.xlsx?dl=0)

The intention is that you can add more permissions, by entering the corresponding IDs in the GREY box (I wish this was a lookup), and then the description will appear. It then generates a list of permissions names, which you can see on the Sheet 2. That is the SQL I have generated so far.

But when I need to do is, for each "y" in the matrix, generate some SQL in Sheet two, somehow.

Comment: Can  you post a few (maybe 10 or so) rows of sample data?

Comment: I've added the sheet now, thanks. Hopefully it's clear. But the grey rows are the ones you edit. The rest is mainly formulas. And Sheet 2 has the data I generate.

Comment: Note, in the sheet, the 'RoleID' isn't there yet, so for now, happy to use the text, while I fix up the sheet to include the IDs.

Comment: Still a little confused, what do you expect the first result to be and where does each field need to link to? from reading your request I am seeing if there is a y then generate a sql insert statement reflecting the role and permission?

Comment: That's correct. I need to iterate though the range (Area where the 'y' cells are), and if that cell has a 'y', I need to generate text that checks the permission ID on the left, and the role name at the top. In the sheet I uploaded, cell O5 should result in a SQL query text that includes the permission ID for that cell (J5), and the Role above (O4). If there is no y, then, no sql is generate.

Comment: The range being O5 to Q100.